# Android, Gradle, настроить оповещение об актуальности используемых библиотек

Tags: android, gradle

Недавно я подсмотрел в одном большом и действующем проекте, состоящим из нескольких модулей, один интересный подход, который позволяет имплементировать одни и те же версии библиотек во все модули разом и в случае необходимости менять версию сразу всех либ всего в одном месте.

Разработчик в build.gradle на уровне проекта пишет сначала:

```
def version = [
        support       : '26.1.0',

        timber        : '4.7.0',
        okhttp        : '3.6.0',
        retrofit      : '2.2.0',
        gson          : '2.8.0',
        playServices  : '15.0.1',
        firebaseMsg   : '17.0.0',
        firebaseCore  : '16.0.0',
        //Ещё много библиотек
        ]
```

Затем(порядок спутан, но это не важно):

```
ext.lib = [
        timber                 : "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:$version.timber",
        okhttp                 : "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$version.okhttp",
        okhttpLogging          : "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$version.okhttp",
        retrofit               : "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$version.retrofit",
        retrofitConverterGson  : "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$version.retrofit",
        retrofitAdapterRxJava  : "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:$version.retrofit",
        gson                   : "com.google.code.gson:gson:$version.gson",
        firebaseCore            : "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$version.firebaseCore",
        firebaseMessaging      : "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$version.firebaseMsg",
        //Ещё много библиотек         
        ]
```

И дальше в buuld.gradle нужного модуля он импортирует те либы, которые ему нужны:

```
...
implementation lib.rxAndroid
implementation lib.rxLifecycle
implementation lib.rxLifecycleComponents
...
```

Мне этот подход очень понравился, и я утащил его в свой проект. Однако это мне в итоге боком вышло: одна из либ очень устарела и выкидывала баг, пока я не догадался её обновить.

Если бы я просто имплементил нужные библиотеки в лоб, IDE подсказала бы что версия которую я хочу использовать устарела. При подходе описанном выше такого нет.

Можно ли как - нибудь усовершенствовать этот подход, чтобы узнавать об актуальных версиях библиотек?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил очень просто, каждый день мониторю это:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases

=)